# Java Regexp Matcher

Tags: java, regex

Simple question about regexps.
I've got

```
String text = "foobar1foobar1";
```

And I need to get part before first 1 (foobar)
When I do something like that:

```
Pattern date_pattern = Pattern.compile("(.+)1");
Matcher matcher = date_pattern.matcher(text);
matcher.group(1);
```

But I recieve "foobar1foobar".

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The `+` quantifier is greedy so it matches as much as possible. You should the [reluctant version](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#reluc) of this quantifier `+?`; your pattern then becomes:

```
(.+?)1
```

Answer (score 2):

Greedy and non greedy regexps. `.+` is greedy and will make the longest possible match. Adding a `?` will make it non-greedy: `.+?`

For your example you don't really need a regexp though, but I guess it was just an example.
Instead you could do this with your example:

```
String firstPart = text.substring(0, text.indexOf('1'))
```

or even a (very simple) regexp in split:

```
String firstPart = text.split("1")[0]
```

Both would be easier to read than regexp for most people. Be careful if you don't have an "1" in there though.

Answer (score 1):

An alternative may be using split function:

```
String s="foobar1foobar2";
String[] splitted = s.split("1");
```

The string you are searching for is in splitted[0].